# Store a response from nested callback function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, async-await, callback

```
var r=[]
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {type: "getRes"}, function (response) {
        console.log(response)
        r = response
    });
});
console.log(r)
```

I am making a chrome extension which I need to fetch the **response** (response is an array) from above for later use (e.g. to pass it to an AJAX call to the backend in my case). I was able to get the response I wanted *inside* the nested callback functions. However, If I would like to store that response to variable **r**, due to the nature of asynchronous calls/callback functions in Javascript, I got an empty array **r** (console shows an empty array outside the function).

After reading on async/wait with shallow understanding, I added async/await to my functions as below and it still didn't work (i.e. `console.log(r)` *outside* the function still shows an empty array). What did I do wrong? I thought JS would await the response then run `console.log(r)`. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Apologize in advance if this is a newbie JS question.

```
var r = [];

(async () => {
    await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, async function (tabs) {
        await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {type: "getRes"}, async function (response) {
            r = await response
            console.log(r)

        });
    })
})()

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippet you should use the asynchronous response inside the innermost callback, more info in [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function)

The second snippet is entirely incorrect because this is not how async/await syntax is used and the `chrome` API methods do not return anything so it's useless to await on them but you can use a [WebExtension polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill):

```
(async () => {
  const tabs = await browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
  const response = await browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {type: 'getRes'});
  console.log(response);
})();
```